# Executing a Jar on Vista with a double click

Tags: java, windows-vista, executable-jar

This pretty much has me defeated.

On XP and earlier versions of Windows you could customise Open With filetypes to include java - jar "myjar.jar", but on Vista this functionality seems to have been removed. I can of course create a .bat file to launch my application, but is it possible to make Vista execute a .jar as required?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can do it from the command line with 2 utilities.

The first one, ASSOC, is used to create a file association. To verify if there is one defined for JAR type :

```
>assoc .jar
.jar=jarfile
```

If not found then create it with :

```
>assoc .jar=jarfile
```

The next step is to define the association. This is done with FTYPE.

To verify if one is already defined , type

```
>ftype jarfile
jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_10\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

Again if not found or the wrong JRE is used, use FTYPE to fix the problem

```
>ftype jarfile="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.5.0_10\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the software JarFix >= 1.1.0 .
There is Vista support included and it "recovers" the .jar association!

download for example here:
http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Miscellaneous/Jarfix.shtml