# Running JAR file on Windows

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have a JAR file named *helloworld.jar*.
In order to run it, I'm executing the following command in a command-line window:

```
java -jar helloworld.jar
```

This works fine, but how do I execute it with double-click instead?
Do I need to install any software?

Comment: Follow the steps described here : [Executing a Jar on Vista with a double click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354664/executing-a-jar-on-vista-with-a-double-click)

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Easiest route is probably upgrading or re-installing the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

Or this:

- Open the Windows Explorer, from the Tools select 'Folder Options...'
- Click the File Types tab, scroll down and select JAR File type.
- Press the Advanced button.
- In the Edit File Type dialog box, select open in Actions box and click Edit...
- Press the Browse button and navigate to the location the Java interpreter javaw.exe.
- In the Application used to perform action field, needs to display something similar to `C:\Program Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_04\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %` (Note: the part starting with 'javaw' must be exactly like that; the other part of the path name can vary depending on which version of Java you're using) then press the OK buttons until all the dialogs are closed.

Which was stolen from here: http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.com/2005/10/setting-jar-file-association.html

Comment: i think the easy way is to right click any ,jar file > open with and chose "Java runtime environment".  :)

Comment: doing so , always gives this error to me " Java platform SE binary has stopped working " ... Can anyone help, what could be the issue?

Comment: @Faizan - Your issue sounds like a separate problem. I see a few SO and Google results for "Java platform SE binary has stopped working". I would check those out.

Comment: there is no File Types tab in Folder options in win 7

Comment: same with Win 10.  did this get moved somewhere with the same functionality? the Windows 10 system 'default app by file type' page seems to not let you edit the execution command to add a 'jar parameter

Answer (score 85):

In Windows Vista or Windows 7, the [manual file association editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows/394628#394628) has been removed.

The easiest way is to run [Jarfix](http://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html), a tiny but powerful freeware tool. Just run it and your Java apps is back... double-clickable again.

Comment: it would be great if someone somewhere could detail the changes this executable makes so that someone could choose to repeat it manually without exetuting some random strangers compiled code.

Answer (score 77):

If you need to distribute your .jar file and make it runnable at other people's Windows computers,
you can make a simple .bat file like this in the command prompt:

```
java -jar MyJavaTool.jar
```

and place the .bat file in the same directory as your .jar file.

Comment: But how is the .bat executed? Would this be the same strategy to get the Java application to open up a command-line session as well?

Comment: Well no, you would just open the bat file. I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 35):

If you have a jar file called Example.jar, follow these rules:

1. Open a `notepad.exe`
2. Write : `java -jar Example.jar`
3. Save it with the extension `.bat`
4. Copy it to the directory which has the `.jar` file
5. Double click it to run your `.jar` file

Comment: Great way to run a jar on Windows!  It also doesn't hide the command line input, so I was able to see why my jar wasn't running like I thought it should.  Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

An interesting side effect of this causes a problem when starting runnable jar files in the command prompt.

If you try (in a command prompt):

```
jarfile.jar parameter
```

No joy, because this is being translated to the following (which doesn't work):

```
javaw.exe -jar jarfile.jar parameter
```

However, the following command does work:

```
java.exe -jar jarfile.jar parameter
```

If you change the association in file manager as described above to:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\j2re1.4.2_04\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

Then you can type:

```
jarfile.jar parameter
```

in the command prompt and it will now work!

EDIT:(However you then get a black console window when you run a form based (non console) Java app, so this is not an ideal solution)

If you run these jar files by double clicking them in windows, no parameters will be passed so your Java code needs to handle the stack overflow exception and include a "press a key" function at the end or the window will just disappear.

In order to pass a parameter in windows you have to create a shortcut to the jar file, which includes the parameter in the target line (right click on the shortcut and select properties) you can not add parameters to the jar file icon itself in this way.

There isn't a single, consistent solution here, but you would have the same problem with any other console application.

There is a windows freeware application called "bat to exe" which you can use to create an exe file from a .bat file with the apropriate command line in it. you can also embed the jar file in the exe with this application, and make it clean it up when it has finished running, so this may be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 10):

In Windows XP <sup>*</sup> you need just 2 *shell* commands:

```
   C:\>ftype myjarfile="C:\JRE1.6\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %* 
   C:\>assoc .jar=myjarfile
```

obviously using the correct path for the JRE and any name you want instead of `myjarfile`.

To just check the current settings:

```
   C:\>assoc .jar  
   C:\>ftype jarfile
```

this time using the value returned by the first command, if any, instead of `jarfile`.

<sup>*</sup> *not tested with Windows 7*

Comment: An anonymous user tested this with Windows 7 (JRE 7).  They say it works if you run cmd as admin.

Comment: Best solution in my eyes. Works up to Windows 10. The commands ftype and assoc should run in a command prompt windows with admin privileges.

Answer (score 10):

First set path on cmd(command prompt):

```
set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin"
```

then type

```
java -jar yourProgramname.jar
```

Answer (score 9):

In regedit, open `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\java.exe\shell\open\command`

Double click on default on the left and add -jar between the `java.exe` path and the "`%1`" argument.

Comment: This was it. Thanks. All the other things did not help.

Comment: 4 years later AdoptOpenJDK Java 11 - One and only solution that worked. Thank You.

Comment: Shame, I cannot bookmark this answer. Works!

Answer (score 7):

There is way without requiring user to do changes on his PC. Runtime.getRuntime.exec() allows us to start cmd.exe and execute commands inside of it. So, it's possible for java program to run itself in command prompt when user clicks .jar file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if(args.length == 0) {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start java -jar " + (new File(NameOfClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath())).getAbsolutePath() + " cmd");
    } else {
        //code to be executed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Besides all of the other suggestions, there is one other thing you need to consider. Is your helloworld.jar a console program? If it is, then I don't believe you'll be able to make it into a double-clickable jar file. Console programs use the regular cmd.exe shell window for their input and output. Usually the jar "launcher" is bound to javaw.exe which doesn't create a command-shell window.

Answer (score 5):

I´m running Windows 7 x64 and was unable to use any of these fixes.

This one worked for me afterall:

http://thepanz.netsons.org/post/windows7-jar-file-association-broken-with-nokia-ovi

There is an archive which you can download containing a .bat file to run, but check the path of the actual javaw.exe!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You want to check a couple of things; if this is your own jar file, make sure you have defined a Main-class in the manifest.  Since we know you can run it from the command line, the other thing to do is create a windows shortcut, and modify the properties (you'll have to look around, I don't have a Windows machine to look at) so that the command it executes on open is the java -jar command you mentioned.

The other thing: if something isn't confused, it should work anyway; check and make sure you have java associated with the .jar extension.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatelly, it is not so easy as Microsoft has removed advanced file association dialog in recent Windows editions. - With newer Windows versions you may only specify the application that is going to be used to open .jar file.

Fixing .jar file opening on Windows requires two steps.

1. Open the Control Panel, and chose "Default Programs -> Set Associations". Find .jar extension (*Executable JAR file*) there, and pick Java as default program to open this extension. It will probably be listed as "*Java Platform(SE)*". A faster alternative perhaps is straightforward right-click on a .jar file, and then change associated program by clicking on the "Change..." button.
2. Now open the regedit, and open the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command` key. Luckilly for us, we may specify parameters there for the `(Default)` value. On my Windows system it looks like: `C:\app\32\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*` but in most cases it is the following string: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*`

NOTES:

- Do not use `java.exe` there as it will open the shell window.
- The *jarfix* tool mentioned in this thread most likely does nothing more than the registry modification for you. I prefer manual registry change method, as that implies that system administrator can "push" the registry change to all workstations in the network.

Comment: Direct registry editing worked for me because jarfix no longer detects JRE 11.

Answer (score 2):

Create `.bat` file:

```
start javaw -jar %*
```

And choose app default to open `.jar` with this `.bat` file.

It will close `cmd` when start your `.jar` file.

Comment: This is the only right answer to launch the jar by click for java 11. But you need to do **once** a bit more  :  **uninstall lower jdks(optionally), right click a jar file->open with-> choose another app->check 'always use...' checkbox->apps on this comp(or such this)->navigate to the bat->launch**

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem, on Windows 10
**The solution:**

1. Check your JAVA_HOME and JAVA_PATH.
   https://javatutorial.net/set-java-home-windows-10
2. Use Jarfix to restore the assiciation between `.jar` and `javaw.exe`
   https://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Another way to run jar files with a click/double-click, is to prepend "-jar " to the
file's name. For example, you would rename the file **`MyJar.jar`** to **`-jar MyJar.jar`**.

You must have the `.class` files associated with `java.exe`, of course. This might not work in all cases, but it has worked most times for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Windows 10. I fixed it using **righ-click** on the "**helloworld.jar**" and go to **properties** and click on **change** button under "Opens with:" and select "**Look for another app on this PC**". In the "**Open with...**" dialog box, go to your Java folder location on your PC and open corresponding jdk folder and then open the **bin** folder and select "**javaw.exe**" from there. Then next time your "**helloworld.jar**" will open the normal way.

Usual java location example : "**C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin**".

Comment: Does not work on my Win10. Also there is no Java/JDK, only Java/JRE folders

Answer (score 1):

**PreScript**: If your prompt appears and disappears immediately, the reason it does so is that your program gets executed and auto shut. Try putting a scanner in the end to terminate and it'll keep your prompt waiting for input before terminating. (Or use delay maybe)

Was in the very same situation, where running .jar from cmd was working fine, but double clicking did nothing.

Solution:
Open any text editor and write the command line:
 java -jar Example.jar
Save the file as a .bat file.
Run this bat file to get the needed output.

Taking it one step forward, you can convert this bat file to exe file using a simple GUI tool like Bat To Exe Converter.

Now you can share your .jar as a distribution in .exe file which anyone can use just make sure you keep all the files together. (Especially the .jar and .bat file cause .bat is only a cmd prompt)(How it feels logical)

I am fairly new to development and learning a lot. Please excuse for any mistakes if committed. Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you use eclipse for making your java files, you can choose to export it as a runnable jar file. I did this with my programs and I can just click on the jar and it will run just like that. This will work on both windows, as well as os x.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be guaranteed to work though, according to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4881136/1743811)

Answer (score 0):

Making a start.bat was the only thing that worked for me.

open a text document and enter. java -jar ***whatever yours is called*** .jar

save as start.bat in the same folder as the .jar file you want to execute.  and then run the. bat

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run the jar file by double clicking on it, you have to create it as a "**Runnable JAR**". you can do it simply with your IDE.

If you're using eclipse, follow these steps :

```
    To create a new runnable JAR file in the workbench:

1.From the menu bar's File menu, select Export.
2.Expand the Java node and select Runnable JAR file. Click Next.
3.In the  Opens the Runnable JAR export wizard Runnable JAR File Specification page, select a 'Java Application' launch configuration to use to create a runnable JAR.
4.In the Export destination field, either type or click Browse to select a location for the JAR file.
5.Select an appropriate library handling strategy.
Optionally, you can also create an ANT script to quickly regenerate a previously created runnable JAR file.
```

more information can be found on Eclipse help Page: [LINK](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There are many [methods](http://www.internetgeeks.org/tech/computer/how-to-open-jar-files-windows/) for running .jar file on windows. One of them is using the command prompt.

Steps :

1. Open command prompt(Run as administrator)
2. Now write "cd\" command for root directory
3. Type "java jar filename.jar"
   Note: you can also use any third party apps like WinRAR, jarfix, etc.

Answer (score 0):

> use `.bat` file:

Put your command in a .bat file. here, your command will be `java -jar path\yourJarName.jar`.
`Something like: java -jar C:\workspace\myApplication.jar`

Save it and double click on bat file to run your jar.

Answer (score 0):

For compiling:

```
javac  -cp ".;./mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar;mybatis-3.0.1.jar;ibatis-2.3.0.677.jar" MainStart.java
```

For running:

```
java  -cp ".;./mysql-connector-java-5.0.8.jar;mybatis-3.0.1.jar;ibatis-2.3.0.677.jar" MainStart
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I faced this problem too. I got around it by making a .bat runner for my jar file.

Here is the code:

```
class FileHandler{
   public static File create_CMD_Rnner(){
      int exitCode = -1625348952;
      try{
           File runner = new File(Main.batName);
           PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(runner);
           printer.println("@echo off");
           printer.println("title " + Main.applicationTitle);
           printer.println("java -jar " + Main.jarName + " " + Main.startCode );
           printer.println("PAUSE");
           printer.flush();
           printer.close();
           return runner;
       }catch(Exception e){
           System.err.println("Coudln't create a runner bat \n exit code: " + exitCode);
           System.exit(exitCode);
           return null;
       }
   }
}
```

Then in Your Main application class do this:

```
public class Main{
    static String jarName = "application.jar";
    static String applicationTitle = "java Application";
    static String startCode = "javaIsTheBest";
    static String batName = "_.bat";


    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        if(args.length == 0 || !args[0].equals(startCode)) {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(FilesHandler.create_CMD_Rnner());
            System.exit(0);
        }else{
            //just in case you wanted to hide the bat
            deleteRunner();
            // Congratulations now you are running in a cmd window ... do whatever you want
            //......
            System.out.println("i Am Running in CMD");
            //......
            Thread.sleep(84600);
        }
    }


    public static void deleteRunner(){
        File batRunner = new File(batName);
        if(batRunner.exists()) batRunner.delete();
    }
}
```

### Please Note that

> 1. this code (my code) works only with a jar file, not a class file.
> 2. the jar file must have the same name as the String "jarName" is the Main class