# .jar working in command line but NOT in windows explorer

Tags: java, command-line, windows-explorer, executable-jar

I have an SWT application that I'm trying to create a runnable .jar for; unfortunately, I cannot seem to run it from Windows Explorer, as I get an error from the Java Virtual Machine Launcher stating it:

> "Could not find the main class gui.MainWindow. Program will exit."

However, it will run through command line

```
java -jar xxxxx.jar
```

I have spent a considerable amount of time looking through threads that have lead me to:

1. edit the manifest file
2. switch through the runtime versions of javaw.exe

all to no avail.

I am creating the executable .jar file in eclipse (including my referenced swt libraries), and have also tried the fat-jar plugin.
Again, it will run *inside* of eclipse with no issues.

I cannot afford a work-around such as a .bat or turning it into a .jex

I have a nagging feeling it is down to me being on a 64-bit system, however, I have gone through both 64-bit and 32-bit versions of javaw.exe as previously stated.

Any suggestions would be more than welcome.

Comment: Have you checked this entry?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows

Comment: I just have, unfortunately it has not aided my cause.

Comment: I removed the swt tag since the question did not relate to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just re-installed the JDK and JRE for 64-bit systems and have used [Default Programs Editor](http://defaultprogramseditor.com/)

to re-assign the .jar association to the 64-bit jre6 javaw.exe, which, seems to have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your app. has a GUI, launch it using [Java Web Start](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml).