# Run java app created in eclipse package structure in ubuntu terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, terminal

I am sure this is a very newbie question, but writing Java app after years. I have written a simple java code to print "HelloWorld"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(" inside MAIN !!!");
}
```

Now I have created my project in eclipse & the structure is "/home/workspace/HelloWorld/src/com/android/test/helloworld/HelloWorld.java" & eclipse creates the .class at "/home/workspace/HelloWorld/bin/com/android/test/helloworld/HelloWorld.class". This runs successfully in Eclipse console. Now I want to run it though my Ubuntu 11.04 terminal.
If i `cd` upto the .class parent folder & use `java .HelloWorld`, it throws an ClassNotFoundException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: /HelloWorld
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .HelloWorld

If I write the same prog with the source file & class file generated in the same default package, I am able to run it through the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cd /home/workspace/HelloWorld/bin/` and run

```
java com.android.test.helloworld.HelloWorld
```

You must always use the classes with their full qualified name (package + class name)

Comment: Thanx beder !! I had somehow missed this out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also note the answer here:
[Runnable jar file generated by Eclipse wont execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881136/runnable-jar-file-generated-by-eclipse-wont-execute)

Basically if you had Eclipse export your project as a "runnable jar" you can run it with:

`java -jar YOURJAR.jar`