# How to access the reviews of old version of an app in itunesconnect?

Tags: iphone, itunes, app-store-connect

I have been pleased to see my application updated to the new version I submitted to the appstore recently. But I was surprised to see that in itunesconnect, I could not access to the information about the first version anymore.

In particular, I would like to see the customer reviews of the previous version of my app. It seems they have been deleted.

Is there any way to retrieve them?

Thanks !

Christophe

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use [App review finder](http://www.massycat.co.uk/iphonedev/AppReviewsFinder/index.html) which is pretty ugly, but does the job. It also allows you to find reviews for all countries on the App Store

Comment: this looks interesting, do you run it on MacOs? Do you know if it is possible to run it on Windows as well? I dont find any documentation to install this program on their website...

Comment: Actually it's a JAR so you can run in on Mac OS, linux and windows. On mac os you just need to open the jar, I'm not sure it is that straightforward in windows, you need to find a way to open JAR (Java Archives) files and it will work. And there is no installation program as it's just an executable. UPDATE : here's a topic about that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows

Comment: Really convenient, it does the job!!