# I Cant get a .jar file to run after being double clicked on windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, jar, click, batch-file

i have tried several things so far, i have used a .bat file to run it, and it opens up the command prompt, but closes right after opening. i have a manifest.txt file already created along with the .jar. If i type -java -jar DesktopApplicationRunner.jar in a command windows that is already up it will run the program.

my .bat currently says:
-java -jar DesktopApplicationRunner.jar

Comment: It's been years, but I believe you want to use `javaw.exe` in this situation.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i need the command window for input, my program currently has no visual elements to it.

Comment: have you tried `javaw -jar app.jar`? that is assuming `javaw` is in your `%path%`

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows

Comment: were is the view found on the windows 7 windows explorer? I cant seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

- Apologies just read your comment saying you have inputs. your problem is using the bat file, unless you have user inputs, the application will start, open the command line, then close when finished, the best way is to manually type in the command line, so it doesn't close the view down afterwards, sorry if this makes no sense. 
  -Ian