# How can I execute a runnable .jar file by double clicking on it?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have .jar file generated from three sources:

1. Netbeans
2. Eclipse (using export)
3. From cmd (jar cvmf MANIFEST.MF output.jar input1.class input2.class ...)

In the last process, I created a blank MANIFEST.MF and then the command.
 When the file got archived in .jar, I opened it with WinZip and edited the MANIFEST.MF. I added Main-Class:input1.

All three sources run fine on cmd through java -jar output.jar. But nothing happens on double-clicking them.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434292/i-can-run-jar-files-through-cmd-but-i-cannot-double-click-them) solution as well. I also have set the default for .jar as javaw.exe but still does not run.

How to fix this?

Comment: did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827164/why-does-my-jar-file-execute-at-cmd-but-not-on-double-click?

Comment: check this as well ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows

Comment: What is your program supposed to do? Does it load a swing gui?

Comment: My program is supposed to show a sorted list of numbers. Is it necessary for jar to have GUI for it to run on double clicking? To be more clear, when I look into my jar archive using winzip, it has two `.class` files and a folder `META-INF` which contains MANIFEST.MF only. Nothing else.

Comment: when you export as jar , use the **executable jar** option . and pack all req files into it

Comment: @SrinathGanesh That I did in eclipse. Does Netbeans provide that option?