# Java .jar "Open With" Windows Explorer continually spawns Explorer processes

Tags: java, windows-7, explorer

Wondering if anyone can tell me why trying to open a .jar file with Win7 Explorer ("Open With" C:\Windows\explorer.exe) would cause the computer to continually create (over 200+ in a couple seconds) explorer processes?

Thanks!

Comment: Never heard something about this problem! Have you tried to execute the JAR through the windows shell? Same problem?

Comment: Nope.  That works.  And I CAN execute the .jar through explorer, but the problem comes up when I Right-Click on the .jar and say "Open With -> Windows Explorer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe do you want to view the contents of the jar? Take a look to this [page](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/w7itproappcompat/thread/c32bbb7b-6f81-42a0-a048-143b305c39ca). Or try with what is written on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows) if you want to execute the jar without the command shell.

EDIT:

The problem of windows explorer is described in this [page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/explorerexe-keep-spinning-new-processes/c20b9e6e-3aa4-4a34-8371-83e971b59b19) and in [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproperf/thread/9237ca68-645c-4718-9a51-24788f312c4b) too.

Comment: That was what I was trying to do (thanks!) but I'm mostly interested in why a couple hundred `explorer.exe` processes were created when I initially tried.

Comment: @BenCole This problem you have is described in http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproperf/thread/9237ca68-645c-4718-9a51-24788f312c4b

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/explorerexe-keep-spinning-new-processes/c20b9e6e-3aa4-4a34-8371-83e971b59b19

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you are trying to open a jar file using Windows Explorer...change the properties...set it to run with java.exe....everything should be fine...and coming to the 200+ question...unless it is a virus or something, it should not behave in such a way...strange to see that happen....try opening other jars in a similar way...you'll get to know the problem and the eventual solution...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with opening JAR files.

From here(thanks Alberto Solano):https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9237ca68-645c-4718-9a51-24788f312c4b/windows-7-hangs-when-opening-a-file-with-explorerexe?forum=w7itproperf

This works(thanks MVied):

- Run Registry Editor
- Browse to \HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-(random numbers with dashes)\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts(whatever file extension is broken, i.e. '.jpg')\
- Delete the folder called 'UserChoice'