# How to make a .jar file run without cmd

Tags: java, jar

Sorry if this a little dumb, but I have a .jar file that runs great when i type java -jar quiz.jar. But it doesn't work when i just double click on the file. I have it set to open with java.exe, and all my other .jars work fine. it's just the ones i've created. Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you double click?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is adding an option in your context menu (using registry).
For example, you can copy this code into a .reg file and run it.
You should have a "Run Jar" option in your context menu. I did it on my Windows installation and it works great.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Run Jar]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Run Jar\command]
@="java.exe -jar %1"
```

If want to remove this option, create and execute a new .reg file which contains :

```
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Run Jar]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply by doing:

1. right-click on the JAR,
2. "Open With...",
3. and then select the `javaw.exe` from your JRE's `bin` folder,
4. tick the "always use the selected program to open this kind of file".

Note that it has to be `javaw.exe`, not `java.exe`. Do browse to the correct location yourself to make sure.

This [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9753103/453590) should work as well.

Comment: Yeah, but any other .jar works fine. It's just the ones i've created

Comment: You have a main class defined in the manifest? (I assume so, considering you can run from the command line you gave)