# How to create a cmd file to run jars?

Tags: java, jar, cmd

I have literally tried everything to try and make my jar files executable by double clicking. But i have come to the conclusion that either I need some major help because my java installation has a problem, or I need to create a .cmd file to automatically run them properly. The code in the file would be like this:

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

What would i replace `myfile.jar` with so that windows puts in the file extension of what i'm trying to open? Thanks.

Comment: How are you building the jar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to run .jar file by double click on windows 7 (64)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64)

Comment: Java won't run any jar files on my pc

Comment: @LukasKnuth, more than that - if the OP built that jar themselves, they'd need some `Main-Class` attribute in their manifest file for java runtime to locate the class to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a `.cmd` file to run your jar, then such a file could look like this

```
@ECHO OFF
SET JRE_HOME=<path to your jre>
%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe -jar myfile.jar
```

Note that here the option `-jar` that implicitly means that `myfile.jar` contains all your dependencies and you cannot extend the classpath to include other dependencies. Also using the this option require your mainifest to have the attibute `Main-Class` which tells which class to run / is the entry point for your program.

Better yet include `myfile.jar` in the classpath an pass your main class to `java.exe`

```
@ECHO OFF
SET JRE_HOME=<path to your jre>
SET MY_CLASSPATH=<jars/libs your app depends on separated by semicolon>;myfile.jar
%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe -cp %MY_CLASSPATH% <your main class>
```

Finally if you want to make an `.exe` of your java programm then you might want to use a `wrapper` like [jsmooth](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/&ei=ZKA1UtaFDM6ZhQfwtIHgDg&usg=AFQjCNFll5fA0eEeIJIiAQ5xZ6kJxrqIwQ&bvm=bv.52164340,d.ZG4) which bundles your jar and all it's dependencies into a single `.exe` file

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, you're right, I should have named it something else, or at least expand it, but not completely overwriting it. Thanks for pointing that!

Answer (score 1):

I Reinstalled Java, and now it works fine. Apparently, I had set WinRAR to be the default Jar opener for Minecraft modding. Re-installing Java reset the .jar extension, making the JRE the default instead of WinRAR.

Answer (score 0):

create a batch file
open note pad type the following

```
set path="...<where u install java>/bin"

java -jar myfile.jar
```

save the notepad as filename.bat and put it in folder containing jar file double click it automatically run

just for example i give you a sample

```
@echo off
set path="F:/java/bin"
java -jar myfile.jar
pause
```

save it as filename.bat put it in a folder that contain filename.jar

if u can't success in above
try this in batch file (it work if you install java runtime (jre)

```
set path =c:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe 
java -jar ImageEditor.jar
pause
```

ImageEditor is jar file 
note  both jar and bat file must be in same folder