# A java Exception has Occurred when Running .jar File of GUI

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have created a GUI project and compile the program using CMD.

For Creating .jar File, I created manifest.txt and made the jar by using following command:

```
jar cmf manifest.txt Client.jar *.class
```

this created a .jar file but when I open the Client.jar a Window pops up saying

"A JAVA Exception has Occurred" but when I run the jar from CMD

```
java -jar Client.jar
```

It runs properly from CMD but not by clicking on it directly.

What Could be wrong ....?

This is my manifest.txt

```
Main-Class: ClientTextEdit
\n
\n
```

\n----> newline

these are the .class files:

```
 ClientTextEdit.class
 ClientTextEdit$1.class
 ClientTextEdit$2.class
 ClientTextEdit$3.class
 ClientTextEdit$4.class
 ClientConnection.class
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64

Comment: Try opening the jar with javaw.exe present in jre's bin folder.

Comment: Is it not possible to use ant, maven or gradle to build your project and generate the jar?