# JAVA, Batch file errors

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, jar

I have an existing Java project that compiles and runs properly through Eclipse.  I have created the following .bat file to run the program sans Eclipse:

```
java -classpath jflashplayer.jar;bin TestProgram
```

The file is saved within the project folder, but not within the `bin` folder (located in same directory as `bin`).  When I try to run the batch, I am met with a large number of runtime errors, the first being

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
```

I'm not sure why I get this error when it compiles and runs properly via Eclipse.  I have the commons-io jar files linked to the project within Eclipse as libraries, and the jar files are themselves located in the project file (same directory as the batch file and the `bin` folder).

Also, I'm not entirely sure what the `-classpath jflashplayer.jar` bit of the batch file is doing.  I am using the jflashlayer.jar library (also linked to the project within Eclipse and in the same location as the other jar files), but I am not sure why it would appear in the batch file.  I edited an existing batch file from a similar project that uses the jflashplayer.jar files, and it has worked previously to leave that part in.

When I write code in Java, I rarely require it to compile/run outside of the IDE, so I usually have troubles when it comes to this part.  Perhaps there is a more robust and foolproof method to run the program outside of the IDE other than the batch file method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file method is fine, but you have to specify all the libraries you're using on the classpath, just like the `jflashplayer.jar`.

In this case, the error you're getting is because the Apache commons-io library is not specified on the classpath. Your command would have to look something like:

```
java -classpath jflashplayer.jar;commons-io.jar;<other jars ...>;bin TestProgram
```

Alternatively, you can create a runnable jar from Eclipse as described [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm). When you select a **library handling strategy**, choose the option **Extract required libraries into generated JAR**. This will make it so that all the library classes you're using are packaged into your application's jar file, and you can just execute it by invoking `java -jar my_application.jar`.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!  I added the libraries in the batch file and it all worked out just great!  Trying to do the executable jar method and am receiving errors (`JAR export finished with warnings` ... which are `Exported with compile warnings:...` and there are a whole bunch of them, basically every class within the project).

Comment: Do these warnings also show up when you're editing your code in Eclipse? Little yellow warning signs to the left of your code? If yes, it's basically those.

Comment: Oh, yep.  A few warnings, but no biggies.  The runnable JAR files aren't working though, regardless of how I include the libraries (Extract, Package, Copy).  Also, I have to type in the export destination myself and have been creating just random file names (ie `C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\tester.jar`).  If it's the file name that is causing the issues, I can fix that, otherwise I'm not sure why it isn't launching the program when I click on the JAR files.

Comment: The file name shouldn't matter. Have you tried running the jar from the command line using `java -jar whatever.jar`? To be able to run the JAR by double-clicking it, I found the following [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64).