# How to execute JAR file without issuing java -jar?

Tags: java, windows, jar

I have hello.jar which I want to execute by just specifying "hello.jar" or by double-clicking it and not by giving `java -jar` command. But this is not happening.

Below is the error that I am getting:-

[image]

As you can see from the above screenshot, `java -jar hello.jar` is working fine which means class path is not the problem.

Below is the structure of the JAR:-
[image]

And the contents of the MANIFEST.MF are as follows:-

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: hello.Main
```

Below are the details of my environment:-
OS: Windows 7 Premium.
Java: Java 7.

I have tried following approach as suggested by @Haloboy but it did not work:-

1. Start "Control Panel"
2. Click "Default Programs"
3. Click "Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program"
4. Double click .jar
5. Browse to: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe for 32 bit
   Windows 7 or C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe for 64 bit Windows 7
6. Click the Open button
7. Click the Ok button

Have tried solutins mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean) but no success.

Any help/pointers on how to associate a JAR file with `'java -jar'` will be helpful.

Comment: first of all  we can't see the error u are getting, but you simply need to change the default program that opens the .jar files [here is what you need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64)

Comment: @QuakeCore The error that I am getting is already shown in the red square box above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a JAR file to execute on a double click in Windows 7, via the following:

> 1.Start "Control Panel"
>
> 2.Click "Default Programs"
>
> 3.Click "Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program"
>
> 4.Double click .jar
>
> 5.Browse to: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe for 32 bit Windows 7 or
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe for 64 bit Windows 7
>
> 6.Click the Open button
>
> 7.Click the Ok button

Comment: Already tried that. Have mentioned your solution in my question for completeness.