# Cannot open runnable .jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have created a `runnable .jar` file on `Eclipse` (`right click on project --> export --> extract required libraries`), and saved it to my desktop. However, the file `doesn't run` when I double click it, and it does not even open when I use the command prompt of `java -jar jarfilename.jar`

**message that shows up reads:**

> unable to access jarfile jarfilename.jar.

I tried:
 1. Downloading and running `Jarfix.exe` to no avail. 
 2. Made sure I have JDK and JRE (I have Java 7 update 79, 8 update 5, and 8 update 71; Java SE Dev Kit 7 update 79 and 8 update 5)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using a Windows PC.

**Edit: After trying out multiple steps, I think the problem was not specifying the .jar file properly. I needed to type java -jar C:\Path to File\myJar.jar.

Now if we can figure out why the double-click doesn't get the file to run...

Comment: Are you sure it's the actual jar and not a shortcut? Additionally, have you tried sudo?

Comment: Read my response below.  Also: please specify your OS - it's important.

Answer (score 3):

Several different things could be going wrong here:

1. It's your OS/Desktop that "runs" a shortcut.

   So on Windows, you need to register file type "jar" with Java:

   [How to run .jar file by double click on Windows 7 (64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64)
2. You also need to have a "runnable .jar file"

   That means you must specify the class with the "main()" you want to run in MANIFEST.MF before you export the .jar file:

   [How to make an executable jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file)
3. Finally, you need to actually "export" from Eclipse *AS* a .jar file.  Double-check the "export" you ran from Eclipse and make sure you explicitly specified "export as .jar"

ADDENDUM:
You seem to have made a couple of additional boo-boos:

4. You do *NOT* want "Eclipse > project> export> extract required libraries".  This copies extraneous junk into your .jar file.  Two disadvantages: a) your .jar will probably be bigger than it needs to be (probably a *LOT* bigger!), and b) you might make your .jar *INCOMPATIBLE* with your Java runtime.  Don't do it :)
5. for the error `java -jar jarfilename.jar`, you must do this:

   a) `cd \my\jar\directory`

   b) `%JAVA_HOME%\java -jar myjarfile.jar`

   ... OR ...

   a) `%JAVA_HOME%\java -jar \my\jar\directory\myjarfile.jar`

PS: You still haven't told us your OS (Windows?  Linux?  MacOS?  Other?).  I'm guessing "Windows"...

PPS:

If you still can't get it working, please follow this tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/

Follow the instructions *verbatim*, using the command prompt.  Post back any questions you have about the *tutorial*.  Once you get the tutorial working (and you should, without too much difficulty), you can apply it back to your original Eclipse project.

Please let us know what you find!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The first method
 (Start "Control Panel"
Click "Default Programs"
Click "Associate a file type or protocol with a specific program"
Double click .jar
Browse C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
Click the button Open
Click the button OK) seemed to yield no result. 

2. For this possible solution, I pasted the code javax.swing... where it told me to, but received two error messages:
Access restriction: the method InvokeLater(runnable) from the type Swing Utilities is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files(x86)/java/jre1.8.0_71/lib/rt.jar

Comment: ..as well as Access restriction: The type swingUtilities is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files(x86)/java/jre1.8.0_71/lib/rt.jar.

3. I tried saving the file as .jar and runnable .jar, but neither method seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I assume in the export wizard you select a WORKING run configuration? That will make sure, that the correct main-class is put into the manifest file.

An jar file is nothing but a "zip". So you should be able to open it with e.g. 7zip and see what´s in it (class-files, manifest, etc).

Please post the error when executing java -jar jarfile.jar

ty