# Automatic open command prompt after run jar app

Tags: java, jar

I have comand line application in Java. Can I write code for double click on JAR file and app start run in comand prompt(automatic open).
Thanks for answers.

Comment: you can make a bat file

Comment: And without bat? Only 1 file?

Comment: you can convert jar file to exe .try [exe4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
Right Click >  Properties > Change > C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin\javaw.exe
```

This has been resolved here [How to run .jar file by double click on Windows 7 (64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64)

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming your problem is, that your jar runs silent in background and you don't see output:*

Usually this is not possible using only 1 file and you would need to create a .BAT with the following next to your .JAR:

```
java -jar jourJar.jar
```

It's possible to use a wrapper, like Fast Snail suggested.

You still can do it with pure java code using 1 file with something like the following, but it's more a hack.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    if(args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("instance")){

        //start your real application code here

    }else{

        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "java", "-jar", "jourJar.jar", "instance"});

    }

}
```

This will open the JAR and then it creates a new CMD process running the JAR again.