# Double clicking jar file wont execute after update JRE

Tags: java, jar

As the title says, my jar file don't executes when i double click on it.

Before I updated the JRE and exported the runnable jar file it worked perfectly fine.

But after the update when i extracted the same project not a single line of code runs.

I have tried the existing answers here with no luck so i decided to ask my own question. My project is a game with pictures, music and textfiles and yes they have the same paths from the working jar.

Regards

**Edit:**

So i moved my project to a new computer with JDK 1.8.0.77 and extracted a runnable jar file but without any difference. However on this computer I can extract another project containing pictures etc and it's working perfectly fine.

The problem might be in my code then but the error must be early because no display comes up and the process doesn't show under processes. How can i debug jar files?

Comment: Which operating system are you on? If Linux, have you set the Jar file as an executable?

Comment: Also have a look a this question, that might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64

Comment: When you updated your JRE, did the update uninstall the older JRE versions?

Comment: Windows 8, it's executable. I did not uninstall the other JRE versions.

Comment: So the older versions are definitely still on your system?  You have checked? Sometimes the update will offer to uninstall the older versions and you have to remove the tick from the box, it has nearly caught me out a couple of times.

Comment: Did you try the answers in the link I posted, reseting your default program opener for .jar files? For example, as Stratwine said: `Right Click ->  Properties -> Change -> C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`

Comment: Yes the older version is on the system. Is it bad? Should i remove them?

Comment: @draken what should I right click? Eclipse my jar file?

Comment: I always keep them. I need older versions for different apps etc

Comment: Your Jar file that isn't running anymore @ViktorLindblad

Comment: Have you checked your JAVA_HOME path? That can sometimes cause a conflict.

Comment: Nothing happens @draken. I have not checked JAVA_HOME path how do I do that?

Comment: Define nothing happens, were you able to follow the steps and then when you double clicked on it, it did nothing?
For setting JAVA_HOME, read up on the notes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Comment: I followed the steps and nothing happens when i double click.

Comment: Did you manage to set the JAVA_HOME to your jre location?

Comment: I followed the steps withouth sucess. I have edited my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was my code all along, one of my 100 classes was creating a textfile and it seems like the jar file crashes when it did.

Sorry for taking up your time but I appreciates your answers. Now I have better understandings using JRE/JDK and jar files.

Thanks

Comment: It's no problem, the main thing is that you learnt from it :)

Comment: Yes your right, but it feels like I could have sorted this out if I looked through my code properly.

Comment: It happens sometimes, at least you gained something from the experience