# Exported eclipse runnable .jar will not run

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

So i'm pretty new to programming and java and I finished a Prime number program. It runs in the cmd and doesn't use any GUI. When I try to double click it the cmd window pops up for like a frame then disappears. When I try to run it with the command "java -jar _____.jar" it works fine and it works fine in eclipse. Earlier I was getting an error saying that I don't have a main manifest attribute but it seemed to go away. If you guys know the fix to the main attribute thing I could try that. Other than that anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So, it works or not? You say it runs fine from the command line

Comment: What version of java are you using? Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: What I was saying was, It works in the cmd but I can't get it to work when you double click the .jar file. And I'm running windows 10 and java 8. Sorry about the lack of information, new to this stuff!

Comment: @codenameveg check comments of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8511277/1166537 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows) to a previous similar question.  They have some good solutions there.

A simple one to try starting out is [JarFix](https://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html) which will re-associate .jar files with the right java exe.

If your program is immediately closing upon running, try adding snippet at the end of it to keep the process alive.

```
System.out.println("Press enter to close.");
try {
    System.in.read();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This didn't work, I guess I should've added that I already have it ask you to enter a number before it ends.

Comment: You could try adding some code at the end of your execution logic to wait a few seconds just to confirm whether this is the issue. `Thread.sleep(10000);` will make it wait 10 seconds.

Comment: The best fix I've found thus far is creating a .bat file to run the command java -jar ___.jar as well as adding the "Press enter to continue" thing that jtwaller suggested. Ill continue to search for a complete fix.

Comment: Hey jtwaller, any chance you could repost that "press enter to exit" line of code, I am on a different computer and I can't find it.

Comment: Sure, added above.  Please don't forget to accept my answer if we have solved the problem.  (It's the checkmark under the up and down arrows to the side of my submission.)