# Unable to run jar file in Windows by double clicking

Tags: java

I am trying to run a very simple program by double clicking my Jar file with javaw.

It runs fine from Netbeans AND from the command line.

My registry path to javaw:

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*

What is going wrong here? How can I make this work when I double click the Jar?

Comment: I've never run a jar by double clicking. I always run in from the command prompt.

Comment: You have Added java to the system path?

Comment: See [How to run .jar file by double click on Windows 7 (64)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JAR file is an executable JAR; I'm not entirely sure how to export an executable JAR from NetBeans (I use Eclipse), but [this](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/generating-executable-jar-file-with-all-dependencies-and-libraries-in-single-jar-using-netbeans-and-eclipse/) article seems to explain it pretty well.

Make sure javaw.exe is the default program for running JARs. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64?rq=1) question addresses that.

There's also a [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) on making and using JARs, and several other StackOverflow questions about it.