# Running JAR file on Windows 10

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have made a Jar file, but I cant make it to run by double clicking.
It works fine using `java -jar name.jar` or by making a batch file.
I have already reinstalled jdk1.8.0_102, set the `JAVA_HOME` variable and `javaw.exe` in the jre folder is already the default program to run it.
so how do I make it to run by double clicking?

Comment: This question has already been answered, try look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64

Comment: @Emax I did read those, none of them worked for me.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511277/207421) is the answer.

Comment: I downloaded a .jar file that I couldn't open. What worked for me was to download the latest version of Java: http://java.com/en/, just in case other people in the same situation as me came to this question

Comment: you may have different versions of JDK installed in your computer. In that case take a look at this solution:[https://stackoverflow.com/a/56334577/1068538](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56334577/1068538)

Answer (score 20):

How do I run an executable JAR file?
If you have a jar file called Example.jar, follow these rules:

```
Open a notepad.exe.
Write : java -jar Example.jar.
Save it with the extension .bat.
Copy it to the directory which has the .jar file.
Double click it to run your .jar file.
```

Comment: Amazing! You are a life saver!