# Why I cant open a jar file by clicking on it?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I made a small java program with eclipse and here I have a trouble. If I try to open it with double click or right click (I tried on Windows and linux) does nothing. But I used "`java -jar ...` " and it worked. How can I do that my program runs just by clicking on it?

Here is my code :

[Main](http://pastebin.com/PXdxBPJe)

[Usuarios](http://pastebin.com/RtAL51Cs)

Utiles---->

```
package main;

public class Utiles {

    private boolean n = false;

    public Utiles() {
        this.n = false;
    }

    public void limpia() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            System.out.println();
    }

    public void salta() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println();
    }

    public void espacio() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            System.out.println();
    }

    public static int countLines(String str) {
        if (str == null || str.length() == 0)
            return 0;
        int lines = 1;
        int len = str.length();
        for (int pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
            char c = str.charAt(pos);
            if (c == '\r') {
                lines++;
                if (pos + 1 < len && str.charAt(pos + 1) == '\n')
                    pos++;
            } else if (c == '\n') {
                lines++;
            }
        }
        return lines;
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't configured your OS to execute `.jar` files with `java` when clicking on them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run .jar file by double click on Windows 7 (64)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64)

Comment: It sounds like .jar files are not associated with your JRE.

Comment: It may start and stop so fast you don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Jar default executable is not set. You can right click on the jar and select properties. Now select change and choose following C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe.

This will make javaw as default app for jar executable.

Comment: Please mark answer as appropriate, whichever worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your program requires a terminal to display the text. When running with `java -jar` you have the terminal open, so you see what you expect. When there is no terminal, one needs to be opened. On windows this requires that you use `java.exe` (not `javaw.exe`).