# How to run jar file on button click in my html page?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have created testing automated script for a webpage of my desktop application. so it runs fine manually from eclipse. I am using selenium web driver and java.

Now I want to create GUI/Easy interface where I can get input from user And RUN my file on button click,so when tester gives input and tap on button ,we see out put fro my script on the samepage

I have exported all functions as Runnable JAR , So now I need to know how can I call and run these runnable jar from html page?on click. Is there any easy way for this?

Please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run .jar file by double click on Windows 7 (64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64)

Comment: From what you're describing I'd suggest running the scripts natively using selenium and npm