# Windows. Application for type of file

Tags: java, windows, jar

Right now my .jar files open with:

```
"C:\Java\jdk-11\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

How can I change path to my jdk? I mean how can I write this command, not just choose path to exe-file?

Comment: add it to your system variable ? google that for windows...

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can set or change the PATH system variable please follow this article.

**This article applies to:**

> Platform(s): Oracle Linux, Red Hat Linux, SUSE Linux, Solaris SPARC,
>   Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Vista, Windows XP, Mac OS X

https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: But I use Windows 10

Comment: Please refer first section Window it has "Windows 10 and Windows 8" step to set system variable.

Comment: Oh. I already done this. I can use java in terminal. But I cannot open .jar files with double clicking

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64