# Could not find main class, jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I need to make an executable jar for my ending project and I keep getting the "Could not find main class"....

I've tried with export > runnable jar and export > jar file (and I did chose the main) in both cases I get the same error.

Details in the runnable:

[image]

My run configurations for the main of the project:

[image]

The dependencies in my project:

[image]

I'm totally lost and i don't know where's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that you can start your application like that:

`java -cp myjarfile.jar Principal.java`

You're double-clicking the file on a windows explorer window? Try to run it from a console/terminal with the command

`java -jar myjarfile.jar`

Please check below link for further clarification . [Running JAR file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows)

Comment: To run an application in a non-executable JAR file, we have to use -cp option instead of -jar. We'll use the -cp option (short for classpath) to specify the JAR file that contains the class file we want to execute:

```java -cp jar-file-name main-class-name [args …]```

Comment: Eg: java -cp JarExample2.jar com.sample.demo.Start

Comment: You can start your jar by double clicking by tweaking some configurations . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64-bit   . Hope it helps

Comment: I just had to delete other jdks, many thanks you were my saviour

Comment: Please upvote my answer if it helped.Thanks :)