# How to export java console programm to Desktop without opening the IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, export

I have a very simple Programm that doesnt have any Frontend or GUI parts. It works just via user input in the console. I wanna build it so i can run it as an application on my PC without having to open my IDE. I want to send it to friends so they just have to open the Programm and it would work.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGd4U.png)

Comment: [Running JAR-Packaged Software](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html) and [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html) and [How to make an executable JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258159/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file), but any decent IDE should be able to help build the JAR

Comment: If you want in to be stand-alone without the need for java to be pre-installed, then you'll need to package your application into an exe file for windows that contains a packaged jar, and there is a different process for OSX and Linux.

Comment: Well I got a .jar file now. But the problem is that when i try to open the Program, nothing happens. As I said i have no GUI or anything in my Program. You can only controll it via the Console with the Scanner package. So can i somehow export a file that when opened shows a Window, like the Console window in Eclipse, in which you could write and get some user input aswell as output.

Comment: How are you trying to "open" it?  Double click on Windows?  The standard way to **run** a Java program that has been exported as an executable JAR is `java -jar <name-of-your-jar-file>`.

Comment: If you want to configure your system so that it will run a JAR file when you double-click it, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511063 etcetera.  You will also need to explain to your friends how to do this, and how to install Java on their systems.

Comment: Another approach would be to use the Java 9+ `jpackage` command that will create a self-contained executable with an embedded JRE.  But I don't think Eclipse supports this directly.  You need to run `jpackage` from the command prompt, or from a Maven / Gradle build.  And the resulting executable will be *platform specific*.

Comment: when I try to run it with "java -jar <name-of-file> " it just says "Error: Unable to access jarfile <name-of-file>. I will try to use the double click method.