# What is System.out exactly?

Tags: java, jar, console, executable-jar, system.out

I noticed that any call to `System.out.println()` from a JAR file that hasn't been started by the command line (i.e. a Runnable JAR file started by user with double-click) won't open the console.

After doing some research, I found multiple answers on the site:

- [System.out.println in jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10373672/3453226)

  > There is no problem doing like that. **But where do you expect to see the output?**
- [What happens to “System.out.println()” in executable jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28477646/3453226)

  > If you run the code in some way that doesn't attach a console - such as `javaw` on Windows, which is the default program associated with executable jar files - then **the output won't go anywhere**. It won't cause any errors - the text will just be lost.

From what I understand, `System.out` does not represent the console. It does represent data which can be handled by anything that needs to display it.
Am I right?

- What is `System.out` exactly?
- How do I open the console from a Runnable JAR file started by user with double-click?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Processes in modern operating systems (and for that matter, several older operating systems) get three standard "streams" associated with them:

- Standard in: Stream-based input (`stdin`)
- Standard out: Stream-based output (`stdout`)
- Standard error: Stream-based error output (`stderr`)

Collectively (and creatively) they're called the [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

`System.in`, `System.out`, and `System.err` are, by default, Java's standard mechanism for writing to those streams.

Programs invoked from the command line are run in an environment where keystrokes in the command line go to `stdin`, and the output of both `stdout` and `stderr` shows as text in the console. They can be redirected to files, etc.

Programs launched via GUIs frequently don't have those streams hooked to anything you can see.

I say "by default" above because you can use calls on `System` to change where those streams point (they have creative names like [`setIn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn-java.io.InputStream-), [`setOut`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut-java.io.PrintStream-), and [`setErr`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr-java.io.PrintStream-).)

> How do I open the console from a Runnable JAR file started by user with double-click?

There's a false correlation there: The fact that the jar is runnable is not why you don't see the streams. If you run a runnable jar at the command line, you'll see its standard output.

Whether you can see that output if you run it without it being associated with a console of some kind will depend on how you're running it and, potentially, how it's written. Many GUI frameworks will redirect standard out and err to a log file. Or the app may offer debugging options that do so. There's no one standard answer there (no pun).

Comment: Do programs invoked from the command line have redirected streams because the console itself is an application, that starts those using the normal Java process API, like any other one would do?

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani: Programs invoked from the command line usually *don't* have redirected streams. Say you do `java -r runnable.jar`: The OS runs the `java` program, providing it with its standard streams. The `java` program loads the jar and does its work to set up the streams for `System` in the newly-loaded JVM to read from and output to the streams it got from the OS.

Comment: If they don't have redirected streams, then how is it possible for the console to handle their IO?

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani: I wouldn't use "redirected" in that sense. The console's streams are provided to the child processes it launches (that's standard OS behavior any time a process launches a child process). The `java` tool then makes those available to the code it's running. To me that's not redirection, but it's probably a semantic point. (Thanks for the edit, btw; I *always* misspell corre...corro...um...that word.)

Answer (score 4):

Here, `System.out` represents the output stream - where your output will go. By default it is set to console. But you can change it to other like - text file. Most often, in large application it is used for logging (usually by new programmer, bad idea). In this case you can see the output in appropriate log file.

Answer (score 3):

`System` is `final` class from `java.lang` package(default package in java) and cannot be instantiated.

`out` is a `static` member field of `System` class and is of type `PrintStream` and its access specifiers are `public final`.

`println` – is an overloaded method of `PrintStream` class. `println` prints the argument passed to the standard console and a newline. There are multiple `println` overloaded methods with different arguments. Every `println` makes a call to print method and adds a newline. Internally, print calls `write()` and `write()` takes care of displaying data to the standard output window.

Here it is how it should look in the inside:

```
//the System class belongs to java.lang package
class System {
  public static final PrintStream out;
  //...
}

//the Prinstream class belongs to java.io package
class PrintStream{
public void println();
//...
}
```

We therefore don't need to ever instantiate a `System` object to print messages to the screen; we simply call the `println` method on the System class's `public static PrintStream` member, `out`.

But you cannot create an object of `PrintStream` and call the `println` function. When you want to print to the standard output, then you will use `System.out`. **That's the only way**. Instantiating a `PrintStream` will allow you to write to a File or OutputStream you specify, but don't have anything to do with the console.

However, you can pass `System.out` to `PrintStream` and then invoke println on `PrintStream` object to print to the standard output. Here is a small example:

```
import java.io.*;
public class SystemOutPrintlnDemo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    //creating PrintStream object
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out);
    ps.println("Hello World!");
    ps.print("Hello World Again!");
    //Flushes the stream
    ps.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: Although it may be correct, my question is not about syntax. I want to know the _feature_ of the class and the world behind them.

Comment: Check my updated answer, I hope it solves your doubt about the features. I suggest you go on [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) for more answers on the `System` class.

Comment: Perhaps I should have said "purpose" instead of "feature". I don't want to know how Oracle developers implemented the `System` class, but how those streams work.