# Java Main file not found

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to create a jar with the jar tool.
Using the following command

```
jar.exe cmfv manifest.txt lol.jar Main.class
```

This generates a jar with the following manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_03 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: Main
```

When I run the jar from command line (java -jar lol.jar) it runs fine. But when I double click the jar in my folder it gives an error: "Could not find the main class: Main.Program will exit."

What could be causing this?

---

After trying some stuff out the Manifest currently looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Created-By: 1.7.0_03 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: code.Main
```

The Main class has a package declaration added. Inside the jar the 'code' folder/package is added. Still have the same error though.

Comment: Did you try running it from the command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows

Comment: @Hassan OP specifically states that he / she ran it from the commandline

Comment: @mtyson it's not my class path to java or javaw which is causing it. I can run other jars just fine.

Comment: can you upload your jar file somewhere and post your link here, because your error is not re-producible for me.

Comment: @SirTroll tx for closing this 3 years later, rofl!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your Main class into a package, and adjust your manifest correspondingly. That should solve the problem

Comment: Added a package declaration to Main.class and moved it to a corresponding path. Still same error though.

Comment: Main-Class: code.Main
and the Main.class is inside a code folder inside the jar

Comment: Is "code" your package? Main.class needs to be in a sub directory tree that matches its package. If it is, it is possible you are not creating your jar correctly

Comment: Was the class rebuilt after changing package declration?  I'm not sure  if the jar utility re-builds the classes.  If not, sometimes i have to do a clean/build to get it to overwrite the .class files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the Main class in your classpath.  When you run it from the command line, your current directory is auto-added to your classpath, this is why it works from there.  When you double click it, you are not specifying the path to the jar as in the classpath.  There are ways to add the class to your classpath in your manifest.
Below is an example of one of my jars.  lib is a folder within the jar,  com/sample/CommandLineClient.class is my main class.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.5.0_12-b04 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Class-Path: lib/args4j-2.0.19.jar lib/axis.jar lib/axis-ant.jar lib/commons-discovery-0.2.jar lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar lib/jaxrpc.jar lib/log4j-1.2.8.jar lib/saaj.jar lib/wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
Main-Class: com.sample.CommandLineClientSysIn
```

Comment: I'm not using any additional jars or classes (apart from some in java.io). So this shouldn't be necessary?

Answer (score 0):

What is the file association with the .jar extensions?

Double click the jar file should make the jar run woth the javaw command.

Try making jar files to be executed by default with javaw.

Also take a look at this: http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-.Jar-Java-File

Comment: javaw from jre7 is associated with .jar