# How to compile and run java file without cmd?

Tags: java, compilation, runtime

Is there any way to compile and run a java file without `cmd`? I want to compile and run java source files by clicking a button like in ides.

Can I do that?

Comment: create a batch file.

Comment: **Yes**. Use an IDE. And/or create a build file using a tool like sbt, gradle, maven, ant, etc.

Comment: Then use an IDE or write a program that does it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I am using a ide,but this is for my knowledge.Can you guys give some references pelase

Comment: If you mean from within side your own program, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25090434/how-to-compile-and-run-inside-the-java-program/25090801#25090801) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544446/how-do-you-dynamically-compile-and-load-external-java-classes/21544850#21544850)

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565437/how-to-run-java-applications-without-using-an-ide-or-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many options.

- use IDE
- Use Build tools
- batch file

for learners it is good to create a batch file(with .bat extension) or use IDE.

simply create a file with anyname.bat and write

```
javac YourPathToFile\yourClass.java
java YourPathToFile\yourClass
pause;
```

save it and double click on that file. (make sure your path variable is already set)

Comment: I need to use it inside my application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the jar file and execute using javaw.exe -jar

Answer (score 0):

If you using Eclipse IDE then Eclipse is automatically compiling your code on the fly.

Or In Eclipse,
You can un-check the build automatically in Project menu and then build by hand by type Ctrl + B, or clicking an icon the appears to the right of the printer icon.