# Output stream while executing a double-clicked java jar file

Tags: java, windows, jar

Hello after following the advice here [Running JAR file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows), I've managed to execute my `.jar` application whenever I double-click on it in Windows (it is a JFrame application).

However, when an certain exceptions occurs, I do `e.printstackTrace();` and generate a custom error message to the UI. When I launch the '.jar' file from the command prompt, the standard error stream is the console. My question is, where does the exception trace go when I run the .jar via double-clicking?

This is a "toy" application, so I would like to avoid a logging mechanism - I only need a place to dump all exception traces for later debugging.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, where does the exception trace go when I run the .jar via double-clicking?

Nowhere. There's nowhere for it *to* go, basically - there's no console attached. You may want to find the user's home directory and put a log file there, or something like that.

(Rather than using `e.printStackTrace()`, I'd suggest using a proper logging framework, whether that's log4j, java.util.logging or whatever. You say you don't want a logging mechanism, but "a place to dump all exception traces for later debugging" sounds like logging to me...)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to avoid using logging for an application that is 300 lines of code (100 are auto-generated) and represent half a day of work. But I like the idea of using the user's home directory. If I don't run into weird permission problems, that should do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Exception stackTrace goes no where. There is nothing attached with it if you directly double click on jar.

The best way to dump all exception traces @ one one place is to use **Logging API.** 
**Ex. Log4j, slf4j.**
They provide the proper framework, using that you can set the proper file name, their destination, what to place in that i.e. degug, error, warning; Moreover you can limit the file size and also decide its existance period.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Given that my program is 300 lines of code, I guess the simplest/ fastest way would be to use the user's home directory as Jon Skeet suggested in his reply below.  Thanks again.