# How to run Luke(Lucene tool)?

Tags: lucene, luke

I had downloaded 'Lukeall-3.5.0' on http://code.google.com/p/luke/downloads/list  It's a JAR file , but i don't know how let it work? Can somebody show me the detailed steps to run Luke?  Thank you!

Comment: Did you try searching google for an answer? I forgot how to run JARs and managed to find out quickly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running Jar file in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows)

Answer (score 24):

You can run eg. from command line issuing `java -jar lukeall-3.5.0.jar` command

Answer (score 12):

If you want the .jar to run on double click then you have to make an association between .jar files and the program that needs to open them, javaw.exe.  You can do this manually by following the steps below, or see [this](http://johann.loefflmann.net/en/software/jarfix/index.html) site for an automatic tool called Jarfix.

- Right click the .jar and go to "Properties"
- Click "Change"
- Click "Browse..."
- Navigate to your Java install folder
- In the "bin" folder you should see "javaw"
- Select "javaw" and click "Open"
- Click "OK"
- Click "Apply"

Comment: It still doesn't work with your steps. i am using jdk1.7 and i open with javaw.exe(path: D:/jdk1.7/bin), but it just show DOS window and it just flash across, then nothing happened .

Comment: Jarfix fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Tried everything including jarfix , javaW commandline but was not running.

Then I downloaded the jar from this link https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/downloads. there are many .jar and .tgz file. I tried the latest one with "type-executable" label on it. And once it was downloaded somehow the extension got changed to .zip. 
1) changed the extension back to .jar
2) right click open with -> Java(this was installed before)

Bingo! Luke opened up!

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to download and install [Java Runtime](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp) to your PC.
Then open command prompt: press `Windows Key + R`, type `cmd` in the textbox and hit `Ok`.
Change directory to your jar file locating folder (using `cd` command), type `java -jar .\yourFileName.jar` and hit enter.

Hope this will work.