# "Could not find main class" on .jar execution

Tags: java, user-interface, windows-7, jar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Jar file in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows)

I created a .jar file for a small GUI Java project with NetBeans. It runs fine from command line. I have .jar files associated with javaw.exe in the JRE. But when I double click the .jar file I get an error:

```
Could not find main class.
```

Comment: I wish there was a way to anti-vote to close.  This is NOT the same problem as the supposed "duplicate" question.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that double clicking is saying that it cannot find the main class means that a JRE is installed.  That is NOT the problem.  It also means that a suitable shortcut exists.  That is NOT the problem ... either.

The problem is (I think) that the JAR file has not been correctly created as an *executable* JAR file.  An executable JAR file must have a Main-class entry in its manifest that tells `java.exe` or `javaw.exe` which class contains the "public static void main(String[])" method that is used to start the application.  Either the manifest entry is missing, or it refers to a non-existent class.

Since this is your program, you need to take a closer look at the way that you are creating the JAR file.  You most likely need to *tell* NetBeans which class to use as the entry point / "main" class.

Answer (score 0):

check this answer: [Running JAR file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows).

In all likelihood, you'll need to supply the `javaw.exe" -jar "%1" %` part in a shortcut, and that will fix the problem.

Comment: Do that for every Java program I run? There must be a better way. Java isn't brand new. Isn't Java meant to run on many different systems?

Comment: I tried running the jarfix.exe program in the other post. It gives me an error too, saying I do not have a JRE installed.