# I have a java project in eclipse. How do I get it so you can run it in the terminal?

Tags: java, jar, terminal

So I have a project with just one java file

Main.java

My workspace is located at /programming/workspace

I added external jar's to the project to use the apache poi.  I can run my program through eclipse and it works just fine but I need to be able to give this program to my friend and be able to run it through the terminal.

I was trying to do Java main where the Main.class file is located but got:

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

How do I get my program to run through a command line that I can give to someone else to run it?

Comment: So how are you running the application exactly? Give the exact command that you use.

Comment: cd /programming/workspace/XLSSearch/bin; java Main

Answer (score 1):

Via Eclipse - > Export - > Runnable jar file -> Set the class which has a `main` method and you want to run when called in the terminal - > Finish (be aware to include the external .jar)

Comment: nvm i got it.  I need to extract it.

Comment: Well it should work by simply double-clicking. If doesn't work, check out to have all JAVA_HOME, PATH, etc set up in the environement system along with JRE properly installed on your system. Check out this answer too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows

Comment: when i double click it, it opens up a file browser with the contents of the jar.

Comment: i can run it by extracting the jar and then using java main in the terminal, though.

Comment: Please check the answer within the link I've added in the previous comment.

Comment: Use `java -jar file.jar` from terminal

Answer (score 0):

select the project. Choose export, export as runnable JAR file