# How should my Java JAR main class path look like?

Tags: java

So I have Test.jar. It's directories look like:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Test/src/test/Test.java
             /MainFrame.java
             /MainPanel.java
             /image.png
```

And my mainfest file looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_13 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: test.Test
```

When launching from command line (java -jar Test.jar) i get such error: *could not find or load main class test.Test*. How to solve it? I know it's problem with Main-Class line in manifest but I dont know how should path look like..

Comment: A jar file is supposed to contain compiled class files. Not java source files. Read [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/).

Answer (score 2):

thats because your jar apparently contains java source files and not compiled java class files.
your jar layout should be

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
/test/Test.class
     /MainFrame.class
     /MainPanel.class
     /image.png
```

your manifest is fine. you should compile your source code files (*.java) to produce *.class files and package those into your jar.

Comment: Thanks! And now - what should I do to run this jar with double-clicking JAR file? I can run it from command line now but Id like to run it like exe files. Because now, when I double-click JAR file it opens and shows its directories. I want application to start when double-cliking JAR file. Is it possible with JAR files?

Comment: @user2102972 - see the answers to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows