# How to run a .JAR file with Delphi

Tags: delphi, jar, pascal

Me and a friend have being trying to do this for a while and regardless of how hard we searched and tried; we just couldn't do it.

But what we are trying to do is Run/Execute a .jar file from delphi ( from like a click of a button )

I did try using ShellExecute (from the ShellAPI) but I didn't how to pass the parameters correctly;

The end purpose we want it to execute his minecraft server (bukkit) with delphi; (These are the usual parameters that are passed "java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar") It may seem pointless, but we thought it would be a good challenge and I'm not one for giving up! So I was wondering is it possible with out using outside libraries and could you help me? I'm not asking for a source I'm asking for assistance and a starting point. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows

Comment: @JanDoggen thanks for the reply; but that didn't really do anything for me; I know how to run one through CMD but I am trying to recreate that in delphi and i was wondering if there is a way

Comment: Jeremehd, to run a jar file from Delphi, you simply take the answer for how to run a jar file *in general* (which Jan linked to), and combine it with the answer to how to run *anything* in Delphi (which you can certainly find for yourself).

Comment: @RobKennedy Oh so i could use the ShellAPI? if i just pass the parameters correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
ShellExecute(
    0, 
    nil, 
    'java.exe', 
    '-Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar',
    nil,
    SW_SHOW
);
```

In order for this to work, the file `minecraft_server.jar` must be located in the working directory when you call `ShellExecute`. If you cannot ensure that then pass the full path to the .jar file.

Comment: Thanks :) I didn't really know the order of the parameters; you have helped a lot