# How to make a Java program be opened by default with Java, on any computer

Tags: java, windows, jar

When I send Java games I created to friends, the JAR file I send them often looks like a RAR file to them. This is because Windows on their computers thinks this file should be opened by WinRar.

They have JRE on their computers, but the default on Windows is that the file they recieve should be opened by WinRar.

The people I send my program can't be expected to guess, that what they need to do is specifically tell Windows to open the file with Java.

Is there a way to make it so that a JAR file I send to somebody, will be opened on his/her computer by default using the JRE?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You're asking if there's a way that you can make your stuff open how you define on a computer that isn't yours? It's Windows, so probably, but it would be unfortunate.

Comment: I think that the better option is use a .cmd or .sh script.

Comment: I am curious why the default for a .jar file would be WinRar rather than Java.  I would consider helping them to change the default application for .jar back to Java on their PCs.

Comment: This stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows mentions an application called jarfix in one of the answers.

Comment: Thats not a problem of java, its a problem on your friends computer. Most likely WinRaR elected to set itself as the default program for jar files (a questionable choice), so its just a configuration issue. It can be easily fixed Explorer -> Right click on jar-file -> Open with -> Select javaw.exe  (check "Always open with this program")

Answer (score 1):

You can consider adding a BATCH script.
Something like `java -jar YourJarName.jar`

You will need two of them - for unix and windows:

Windows start.bat:

```
java -jar YourJarName.jar
```

Unix start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar YourJarName.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool such as [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to wrap the JAR file into an executable.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your JAR file to executable file using [Java Launcher](http://www.syncedit.com/software/javalauncher/).

**OR**

As @lan Roberts answer You can use [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to wrap your JAR to executable. You can download it from [this](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Launch4j-Executable-Wrapper.shtml).