# Java Exception has occurred when opening .JAR file

Tags: java, jar, packaging

I am trying to run a jar file that came with a program designed by BOSCH called EsiTronic. I receive the following error message "A java exception has occurred" I made some research and looked in the other threds of this forum but it did not help me. My gues is that the version I am using is not supporting the version the program was compiled on. I tried running it from CMD to see the detailed error message. If someone can tell me more from this message I will apreciate. I want to point out I am not a programer so my knoledge is limited here.

Thanks!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows

Comment: @nbro That has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @aioobe System output should be in monospace, not proportional blockquote.

Comment: @chrylis That's your opinion.

Comment: @nbro That's my informed and expert opinion. The linked question is talking about being able to launch the jar in the JVM at all. This question is launching the JVM just fine, but there's a problem with the jar's contents.

Comment: what command did you use to run the downloaded file?

Comment: Try to extract its contents and then run them: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/unpack.html

Comment: @chrylis, There's a discussion on this [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258844/how-should-the-error-message-be-formatted/258855#258855). I would argue that this is a *a descriptive error message, in real language*. I have now learned about the `language: none` directive however, which makes code formatting a bit more ok in this case I guess.

Answer (score 2):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file

Theres nothing much that you can do here except re-download the jar file. The jar file probably got curropted during download or even at the time of packaging from the source