# Error: Class names, 'test.jar', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested 1 error on jar file

Tags: java

So before i did the new java update(that deleted all my previous version) i was doing this when i export my project from eclipse and its worked very well. But after the new update of java this happen my programm don't even open and when i try to open them with cmd i got this error (i execute them always with Javac test.jar) and its worked i dont use (javac test.java) in eclipse everything work fine and before the update too everything worked very well.

[image: the error in the CMD]

Comment: Update : its works when i use this commande java -jar test.jar
how can i make it always open like this so when i double click on my .jar file its work 
ps : my program has an Interface so when its open i can see

Comment: Update : when i try java test.jar i got this 
Error : could not find or load main class test.jar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running JAR file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows)

Comment: all my other program work fine just this one doesn't want to open when i double click :)