# How start my application as server from console?

Tags: java, javax.ws.rs

In IntellIJ IDEA I start my Kotlin project like server.
Here my run config:

[image]

Nice. It's start on port 3333.

I use this classes for server

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
```

OK.

But I need to start my application as server from console.

How I can do this?

I try this:

```
java server config.yml -jar com.myproject.jar
```

but I get error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your command line arguments after the parameters for the JVM, e.g.

```
java -jar com.myproject.jar server config.yml
```

If you need to specify a main class which is located somewhere in your Jar do the following:

```
java -cp com.myproject.jar com.myproject.AppStarterKt server config.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You may put your main class in the manifest file or add it as argument. Have a look at this [post](https://www.programmergate.com/run-jar-file-command-line/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm think that's because the invalid arguments you used in `java server config.yml -jar com.myproject.jar`

I think this might be the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1459206/1771375)