# JMeter installation - JMeter.bat file is missing from bin folder

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to install Jmeter but -JMeter.bat file is missing from bin folder -
, I have already installed java 8 and I installed the JMeter from apache website from the binary,
but still, the JMeter file is missing from bin folder
Any help, please ????

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to download **Binary**, not the source package

[image]

Just in case here is the direct link for downloading latest (as of now) [JMeter version 5.2.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-2-1-released-td5728641.html): https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.2.1.zip

More information: [How to Get Started With JMeter: Part 1 - Installation & Test Plans](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-get-started-jmeter-part-1-installation-test-plans/)

If you deleted `jmeter.bat` file by accident you can get a [copy](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.2.1/bin/jmeter.bat) from JMeter Github or just [launch JMeter using ApacheJMeter.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows) file as:

```
java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
```