# NetBeans is Creating a Compressed File not a Jar File

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to build a game that I just made in NetBeans and when I go to build the file it just creates a compressed file that when I extract it it gives me all of classes and not a Jar file. Is there something I am missing or am I a complete idiot? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have attached the build output from NetBeans as well as the directory where the supposed Jar file should be.
[Build output from NetBeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvBo5.png)
[image: Directory of Supposed Jar File]

Comment: That is what a JAR file is, an archive of the object files. It looks like WinRAR has decided it wants to manage the extension, so you need to set it back to the default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running JAR file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows)

Comment: You might want to configure Explorer not to hide file extensions, then you would see that it is a .jar file.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I don't know how to configure explorer to do that but I will keep you updated! Thank you so much again <3

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution,

Just had to change the default program that a .jar file was supposed to open with. Now that I can actually run the file, I have noticed that the icons that are supposed to be on my game board do not load. So I will try to figure that out but I can at least run the file now.

-TL