# How to deploy a postgresql java desktop application?

Tags: java, postgresql, deploying

I've developed a java desktop application with postgresql database using Netbeans, and it works well locally. The question is how to run the application on other devices? what to do with the jar file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows

Comment: Not sure if it's really relevant question unless it involves code. However we need more details. Is it a central postgresql database installation you have on a server or does the client also need to postgresql installed locally?

Comment: Try to be more specific: On what devices are you trying to run the jar file? What errors are you receiving when you try to run the jar?

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari I have a local database created using pgAdmin. The end user must reach this database to retrieve and add data while using the application.

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero On the client device that has no java or database environments. The application works well except the database part, it is unreachable.

Comment: You have to either put the postgresql database on a central server everyone can reach or you have to install a copy of the postgresql database on each and every device that's using your application.

Comment: Are you running the database on a server or locally on each user’s machine? Postgres is not built to easily support bundling with local apps. You might consider another database for that, such as H2 Database Engine (built in pure Java).

Comment: @BasilBourque locally. I've been using H2 but they said that it doesn't work like this! can you please tell me the proper way?