# when launching Jmeter, for the prompt-how do u want to open the jmeter .jar file? Which file to select after C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-folder\bin?

Tags: java, java-8, jar, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

For the Jmeter version 5.5

I have setup the env variables

Path as *C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_341\bin*

HOME_PATH as *C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_341*

Have even checked in the CMD  with the command
`java -version`

I'm not sure with which file inside the bin folder should I be launching  the jmeter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "bin" folder of your JDK installation needs to be in the operating system PATH so [jmeter.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/bin/jmeter.bat) wrapper script would be able to locate `java.exe`

   you can add it to your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) as follows:

   ```
   set PATH="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_341\bin";%PATH%
   ```

   either in your terminal window or add it as the first line to jmeter.bat script
2. `HOME_PATH` variable is not needed by JMeter.

If you're able to run `java -version` you can run JMeter as [`java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows) from its bin folder.

More information: [JMeter Installation: How to Get Started](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)

Answer (score 1):

To run JMeter, run the `jmeter.bat` (for Windows) or `jmeter` (for Unix) file.

Original docs: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#running