# Unable to open .jar Files created by Intellij by double-clicking it

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar

so I got a problem :( I cannot open a .jar file. which was created by Intellij, by double-clicking it.
The MANIFEST File is correct and everything else too. When I want to open it by double-clicking on the .jar file I get this error message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0L5Sa.png)

When I open the file via cmd everything works fine and there is no exception.
The java version is also correct.
I can also open other jar files,which are not build by intellij, by double-clicking.

What can I do?
In the past I was able to open the same jar file build by intellij :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running JAR file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-on-windows)