# Building Jar file using Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, mysql-connector

I have this project on Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) and planning to build the *.jar.
I am to build the project by File > Export > Java.Runnable JAR File > Named the filename of the jar file > Finish.
An error always return to me when running the jar file.

```
Could not find the main class: [package nmame].[Class name of Main class (PSVM) is located].
Program will exit.
```

In addition, MySQL Connector 5.1 was included as Referenced Library for JDBC use.

How can I resolve and be able to build a jar file that is running as runned on Eclipse as Java Application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export the project try selecting the option :

> Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated jar

[image: Screenshot]

This will create a lib folder containing the required dependency libraries ..

*You have also to select a valid launch configuration for the program, to make sure that the MANIFEST file will be created with the MAin class attribute populated correctly .*

When you run the generated jar you should run it with this command line (READ the MANIFEST.MF) :

```
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

or with Main class specified in the command line :

```
java yourjar.jar MainClass
```

Comment: I still get the same error message. How could I set my Main class in the Manifest file?

Comment: Yes, you can open the MANIFEST.MF and see whats inside, but are you running the jar with the -jar option ?

Comment: Sorry, but where can I see the MANIFEST.MF in the project folder. I was just running the jar by double clicking the file. I was hoping building the jar file in Eclipse is easy as building one using Netbeans.

Comment: The `java -jar yourjar.jar` did work. How can I make the jar file runnable itself by just double-clicking the file itself. Similar to the ones built by Netbeans.

Comment: It depends on the file association of your operating system, take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354664/executing-a-jar-on-vista-with-a-double-click